# How to append answer in h1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
I'm trying to do a simple calculator by input value but it doesn't seem to appear on my h1. Can somebody help me? i also want to make the variables work outside the function.


function addition(){
  let $first = $('#first').val();
  let $second = $('#second').val(); 
  $('h1').append($first + $second);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>A Great Demo on CodePen</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type='text' id='firstNum' placeholder='Enter First Number'>
  <input type='text' id='secondNum' placeholder='Enter Second Number'>
  <button id='add' onclick='addition()'>Add</button>
  <button id='sub' onclick='subtraction()'>Subtract</button>
  <button id='multi' onclick='multiplication()'>Multiply</button>
  <button id='divide' onclick='division()'>Divide</button>
  
  <h1></h1>
  
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the HTML on which this code runs. Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` on the toolbar) to create a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering how calculator will work with two inputs but anyway

- Your ids is wrong its `#firstNum` and `#secondNum` not `#first`/`#second`-
- And you need to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to convert string to integer

```js
function addition(){
  let $first = parseFloat($('#firstNum').val());
  let $second = parseFloat($('#secondNum').val());
  $('h1').html($first + $second);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>A Great Demo on CodePen</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type='text' id='firstNum' placeholder='Enter First Number'>
  <input type='text' id='secondNum' placeholder='Enter Second Number'>
  <button id='add' onclick='addition()'>Add</button>
  <button id='sub' onclick='subtraction()'>Subtract</button>
  <button id='multi' onclick='multiplication()'>Multiply</button>
  <button id='divide' onclick='division()'>Divide</button>
  
  <h1></h1>
  
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I suggest to search for a calculator using html,css,javascript there're tons of it out there